# Report generation in PHP (formats required pdf,xls,doc,csv)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

I need to generate reports in my PHP website (in zend framework)

Formats required:

```
PDF (with tables & images) // presently using Zend_Pdf
XLS (with tables & images)
DOC (with tables & images)
CSV (only tables)
```

Please recommend robust and fast solution for generating reports in PHP.

Platform: *Zend Framework on LAMP*

**I know there are some tricky solutions for creating such reports, i wonder is there any open source report generation utility that can be used with LAMP environment**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excel: http://www.phpexcel.net

Comment: It looks promising, I am gonna use it too!

Answer (score 3):

In my LAMP based application, I integrated the ability to generate report with JasperReports successfully.

For that, I use PHP/Java Bridge to communicate with Jasper java classes. You might want to try Zend Server since it provide this component at installation time.

Check this blog, it was a source of inspiration for my final solution : http://www.rjohnson.id.au/wordpress/2007/10/27/bullet-proof-jasper-reports-and-php/

Comment: I will certainly re-try implementing JasperReports using Zend Server. thanks for the reply

Comment: +1 I have integrated PHP-Jasper over JavaBrige on Apache2 Web Server so as Tomcat, and with no doubt this is a powerful fusion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean CSV instead of CVS. For excel and csv files, you can use

```
header("Content-Type: text/comma-seperated-values");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"file.csv";");
```

and

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"file.xls";")
```

respectively. Make sure you turn all formatting off and output only values and comma's for the CSV format, and with the XLS format, you can use regular html tables.

Comment: This works well with CSV and XLS, but how do i create DOC files ?

Comment: DOC files are a little more complicated to do, I am planning on doing something similar with Java and it seems like I'm going to need a library that does the word document creation. You should go on google and see if there are any reasonable libraries that do this in PHP.

Comment: I think **JasperReports** is open source java library that able to do such things in JAVA, I tried it with PHP, but no luck with it.

So i used PHP-Excel library and it's good enough for my usability